# Read XML file to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, elementtree

Can someone please help convert the following XML file to Pandas dataframe:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
 <bathrooms type="dict">
  <n35237 type="number">1.0</n35237>
  <n32238 type="number">3.0</n32238>
  <n44699 type="number">nan</n44699>
 </bathrooms>
 <price type="dict">
  <n35237 type="number">7020000.0</n35237>
  <n32238 type="number">10000000.0</n32238>
  <n44699 type="number">4128000.0</n44699>
 </price>
 <property_id type="dict">
  <n35237 type="number">35237.0</n35237>
  <n32238 type="number">32238.0</n32238>
  <n44699 type="number">44699.0</n44699>
 </property_id>
</root>
```

It should look like this --

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDk8E.png)

This is the code I have written:-

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('real_state.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

dfcols = ['property_id', 'price', 'bathrooms']
df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

for node in root:
    property_id = node.attrib.get('property_id')
    price = node.attrib.get('price')
    bathrooms = node.attrib.get('bathrooms')

    df_xml = df_xml.append(
            pd.Series([property_id, price, bathrooms], index=dfcols),
            ignore_index=True)


print(df_xml)
```

I am getting *None* everywhere, instead of the actual values. Can someone please tell how it can be fixed. Thanks!

Comment: If I can make the question any clearer, please post your comments..

Comment: You can start by posting the XML code not the image.

Comment: are you getting the data through requests or is it an xml file?

Comment: It is an XML file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if the data is simple, like this, then you can do something like:

```
from lxml import objectify
xml = objectify.parse('Document1.xml')
root = xml.getroot()

bathrooms = [child.text for child in root['bathrooms'].getchildren()]
price = [child.text for child in root['price'].getchildren()]
property_id = [child.text for child in root['property_id'].getchildren()]

data = [bathrooms, price, property_id]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df.columns = ['bathrooms', 'price', 'property_id']

    bathrooms   price      property_id
0   1.0        7020000.0    35237.0
1   3.0        10000000.0   32238.0
2   nan        4128000.0    44699.0
```

if it is more complex then a loop is better. You can do something like

```
from lxml import objectify
xml = objectify.parse('Document1.xml')
root = xml.getroot()

data=[]
for i in range(len(root.getchildren())):
    data.append([child.text for child in root.getchildren()[i].getchildren()])

df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df.columns = ['bathrooms', 'price', 'property_id']
```

Comment: @SarthakGirdhar not a problem at all. I would use the second approach if the `len(root.getchildren())` is large so you do not have to create each list individually.

Comment: Yes, I did go with the second approach. Thank you once again!!

Answer (score 3):

Hello all I found another really easily way to solve those question.
reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVrg5-cjr5k

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import codecs

## open notebook and save your xml file to text.xml 
with codecs.open('text.xml', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    tt = f.read()


def xml2df(xml_data):
    root = ET.XML(xml_data)
    all_records = []
    for i, child in enumerate(root):
        record = {}
        for sub_child in child:
            record[sub_child.tag] = sub_child.text
        all_records.append(record)
    return pd.DataFrame(all_records)


df_xml1 = xml2df(tt)
print(df_xml1)
```

for better understanding of ET you can use underneath code to see what in side of your xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import codecs
with codecs.open('text.xml', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    tt = f.read()

root = ET.XML(tt)

print(type(root))
print(root[0])
for ele in root[0]:
    print(ele.tag + '////' + ele.text)

print(root[0][0].tag)
```

Once you finish running the program you can see the output underneath:

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\pycode\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/DestinationLight/try.py
      n35237      n32238     n44699
0        1.0         3.0        nan
1  7020000.0  10000000.0  4128000.0
2    35237.0     32238.0    44699.0

<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>
<Element 'bathrooms' at 0x00000285006B6180>
n35237////1.0
n32238////3.0
n44699////nan
n35237

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had success using this function from the [xmltodict](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/) package:

```
import xmltodict

xmlDict = xmltodict.parse(xmlData)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(xmlDict)
```

What I like about this, is I can easily do some dictionary manipulation in between parsing the xml and making my df. Also, it helps to explore the data as a dict if the structure is wily.