# How to write CSV from XML response in Python?

Tags: python

by the following HTTP request

```py
import requests
import csv

url = 'http://www.culturaitalia.it/oaiProviderCI/OAIHandler?verb=ListRecords&metadataPrefix=pico&set=collezione_pansa_villa_frigerj'

e = requests.get(url)

data = e.text

print(data)
```

I'm having as output this XML file

```xml
<record><header><identifier>oai:culturaitalia.it:oai:culturaitalia.it:museiditalia-work_46880</identifier><datestamp>2018-08-29T17:56:41Z</datestamp><setSpec>museiditalia_opere</setSpec><setSpec>opere_museid</setSpec><setSpec>Beni_culturali</setSpec><setSpec>collezione_pansa_villa_frigerj</setSpec></header><metadata>
<pico:record xmlns:pico="http://purl.org/pico/1.0/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:iccd="http://purl.org/pico/iccd/2.00/" xmlns:oad="http://purl.org/pico/iccd/2.00/oa-d-n/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:smi="http://purl.org/pico/iccd/2.00/s-mi/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:bdm="http://purl.org/pico/iccd/2.00/bdm/" xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/" xmlns:f="http://purl.org/pico/iccd/2.00/f/" xmlns:vra="http://www.vraweb.org/vracore4.htm" xmlns:iccd3="http://purl.org/pico/iccd/3.00/" xmlns:mix="http://www.loc.gov/mix/v20" xmlns:nu="http://purl.org/pico/iccd/3.00/nu/" xmlns:premis="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://purl.org/pico/1.0/               http://www.culturaitalia.it/pico/schemas/1.0/pico.xsd                     http://purl.org/pico/iccd/2.00/         http://www.culturaitalia.it/pico/schemas/iccd/2.00/iccd.xsd                     http://purl.org/pico/iccd/2.00/oa-d-n/  http://www.culturaitalia.it/pico/schemas/iccd/2.00/oa-d-n.xsd                     http://purl.org/pico/iccd/2.00/s-mi/    http://www.culturaitalia.it/pico/schemas/iccd/2.00/s-mi.xsd                     http://purl.org/pico/iccd/2.00/bdm/     http://www.culturaitalia.it/pico/schemas/iccd/2.00/bdm.xsd                     http://purl.org/pico/iccd/2.00/f/       http://www.culturaitalia.it/pico/schemas/iccd/2.00/f.xsd                     http://purl.org/pico/iccd/3.00/         http://www.culturaitalia.it/pico/schemas/iccd/3.00/iccd.xsd                     http://purl.org/pico/iccd/3.00/nu/      http://www.culturaitalia.it/pico/schemas/iccd/3.00/nu.xsd">
  <dc:identifier>work_46880</dc:identifier>
  <dc:title>BROCCHETTA MINIATURISTICA</dc:title>
  <dc:subject xsi:type="pico:Thesaurus">http://culturaitalia.it/pico/thesaurus/4.1#reperti_archeologici</dc:subject>
  <dc:description xml:lang="it">BROCCHETTA MONOANSATA. ANSA A DOPPIO BASTONCELLO ARCUATO CHE SI SALDA SULCOLLO AL DI SOTTO DEL LABBRO ESPANSO. CORPO BACCELLATO CON INCISIONE AD XSOTTO L'ANSA, BASSO PIEDE TRONCOCONICO. VERNICE MALCOTTA CON AVVAMPATURESUL PIEDE.</dc:description>
  <dcterms:spatial>Museo Archeologico Nazionale d'Abruzzo, Villa Frigerj, CHIETI (CH) - ITALIA - sala collezione Pansa - vetrina 1, inv. 3130</dcterms:spatial>
  <dcterms:spatial xsi:type="pico:ISTAT">name=CHIETI; year=2001; code=069022</dcterms:spatial>
  <dcterms:created>SEC. III A.C.</dcterms:created>
  <dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:Period">start=299; end=250</dcterms:created>
  <dc:type xsi:type="mdi:Type">Opere</dc:type>
  <dc:type xml:lang="it">BROCCHETTA MINIATURISTICA</dc:type>
  <dc:type xsi:type="dcterms:DCMIType">PhysicalObject</dc:type>
  <dcterms:isPartOf xsi:type="dcterms:URI">oai:culturaitalia.it:museiditalia-coll_445</dcterms:isPartOf>
  <dc:rights xml:lang="it"/>
  <dcterms:rightsHolder xml:lang="it">PROPRIETA' STATO, Ministero per i Beni e le Attività Culturali</dcterms:rightsHolder>
  <dcterms:isReferencedBy xml:lang="it">Scheda ICCD RA: 13-00008576</dcterms:isReferencedBy>
  <pico:materialAndTechnique xml:lang="it">ARGILLA</pico:materialAndTechnique>
  <dcterms:extent>altezza: cm 9.4</dcterms:extent>
  <dcterms:extent>diametro: cm 6.9</dcterms:extent>
  <pico:preview xsi:type="dcterms:URI">http://194.242.241.163/fedora/objects/work:46880/datastreams/MM135934/content</pico:preview>
  <dcterms:isReferencedBy xsi:type="pico:Anchor">title=visualizza il file Mets; URL=fedora/objects/work:46880/datastreams/export/content</dcterms:isReferencedBy>
</pico:record>
</metadata></record>
```

How can I write to a CSV file the output from my HTTP request? Maybe using Pandas?

Regards

Comment: how would you want your csv to look and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use json format which is easier to deal in python you can play with it as you want. But look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968877/read-xml-file-to-pandas-dataframe) it may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse some of the data with regular expressions.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

# I like to "tokenize" text, if possible.
tokens = [i.strip() for i in sample.split('\n') if len(i) > 0]

# Create a regular expression pattern for  tag values and text values
# Note: the ?P<> part is how we can identify each matching section.
full_pat = r"<(?P<tag>[a-z0-9:\"\.:\= ]+)>(?P<text>[\w\d ]+)<?/?"

# Compile it (for speed, I think)
# The re.I flag means to ignore whether the letter is uppercase or lowercase
p = re.compile(full_pat, flags=re.I)

results_dict = dict()
for i, v in enumerate(tokens):
    res = p.search(v)
    try:
        # Append a dictionary with our tag and text values to our results dictionary.
        results_dict[i] = dict(tag=res.group('tag'), text=res.group('text'))
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Output of results_dict:

```
{0: {'tag': 'identifier', 'text': 'oai'},
 2: {'tag': 'dc:identifier', 'text': 'work_46880'},
 3: {'tag': 'dc:title', 'text': 'BROCCHETTA MINIATURISTICA'},
 4: {'tag': 'dc:subject xsi:type="pico:Thesaurus"', 'text': 'http'},
 5: {'tag': 'dc:description xml:lang="it"', 'text': 'BROCCHETTA MONOANSATA'},
 6: {'tag': 'dcterms:spatial', 'text': 'Museo Archeologico Nazionale d'},
 7: {'tag': 'dcterms:spatial xsi:type="pico:ISTAT"', 'text': 'name'},
 8: {'tag': 'dcterms:created', 'text': 'SEC'},
 9: {'tag': 'dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:Period"', 'text': 'start'},
 10: {'tag': 'dc:type xsi:type="mdi:Type"', 'text': 'Opere'},
 11: {'tag': 'dc:type xml:lang="it"', 'text': 'BROCCHETTA MINIATURISTICA'},
 12: {'tag': 'dc:type xsi:type="dcterms:DCMIType"', 'text': 'PhysicalObject'},
 13: {'tag': 'dcterms:isPartOf xsi:type="dcterms:URI"', 'text': 'oai'},
 15: {'tag': 'dcterms:rightsHolder xml:lang="it"', 'text': 'PROPRIETA'},
 16: {'tag': 'dcterms:isReferencedBy xml:lang="it"', 'text': 'Scheda ICCD RA'},
 17: {'tag': 'pico:materialAndTechnique xml:lang="it"', 'text': 'ARGILLA'},
 18: {'tag': 'dcterms:extent', 'text': 'altezza'},
 19: {'tag': 'dcterms:extent', 'text': 'diametro'},
 20: {'tag': 'pico:preview xsi:type="dcterms:URI"', 'text': 'http'},
 21: {'tag': 'dcterms:isReferencedBy xsi:type="pico:Anchor"', 'text': 'title'}}
```

Convert to a Pandas DataFrame and use the .to_csv() function to write a csv file (I'll let you figure that part out).  Note: We have to make sure our dictionary is parsed correctly, so we have the orientation as 'index,' versus the default value of 'columns'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(results_dict, orient='index')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                              tag                            text
0                                      identifier                             oai
2                                   dc:identifier                      work_46880
3                                        dc:title       BROCCHETTA MINIATURISTICA
4            dc:subject xsi:type="pico:Thesaurus"                            http
5                    dc:description xml:lang="it"           BROCCHETTA MONOANSATA
6                                 dcterms:spatial  Museo Archeologico Nazionale d
7           dcterms:spatial xsi:type="pico:ISTAT"                            name
8                                 dcterms:created                             SEC
9       dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:Period"                           start
10                    dc:type xsi:type="mdi:Type"                           Opere
11                          dc:type xml:lang="it"       BROCCHETTA MINIATURISTICA
12            dc:type xsi:type="dcterms:DCMIType"                  PhysicalObject
13        dcterms:isPartOf xsi:type="dcterms:URI"                             oai
15             dcterms:rightsHolder xml:lang="it"                       PROPRIETA
16           dcterms:isReferencedBy xml:lang="it"                  Scheda ICCD RA
17        pico:materialAndTechnique xml:lang="it"                         ARGILLA
18                                 dcterms:extent                         altezza
19                                 dcterms:extent                        diametro
20            pico:preview xsi:type="dcterms:URI"                            http
21  dcterms:isReferencedBy xsi:type="pico:Anchor"                           title
```